# Can i power my Raspberry pi 3 b+ with a micro-USB to USB thats connected to a USB charger?

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, power, voltage

I read in the manual, that u should charge it with 5V and 2.5 amp, but im not sure. I already read, that a undervoltage can damage the pi and that USB 3.x would be enough, but I still dont know how that is with a USB charger that is connected to a wall socket and not with a USB port of a PC.

Comment: Do you have an existing micro-USB charger and have you checked the adapter / wall wart to check it's output amperage?

Comment: Raspberry Pi is not something that you "charge" .... you power it with a power supply .... the device that you plug into a power outlet is a power supply, not a charger

Comment: @jsotola: It strikes me that the OP's question is about a power supply, and not a battery charger. In any event USB-compliant power supplies serve both roles - the battery charging being taken care of in the system that is drawing power.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, your choice of words suggests that a clarification is needed:

> Batteries are ***charged*** - a RPi is ***powered***

A USB power supply that plugs into a wall outlet will work fine ***if it can source 2.5 Amps***. The power supply should have this specification printed on the housing, or embossed in the plastic body. You don't necessarily need a USB-3.X supply - just make sure the supply is capable fo supplying 2.5 Amps. You may even be able to get by with a bit less than 2.5 Amps if you don't use *peripherals* that draw power; e.g. disk drives.